# Missing core name in path

Tags: eclipse, solr

I am setting up solr on eclipse and tomcat as specified [here](http://sarozz.blogspot.in/2011/01/setting-up-local-solr-server-with.html). I am using solr 3.5.0 and eclipse Indigo on a debian. When I run solr through eclipse, I am able to reach the home page. But the admin console won't work and throws a 404 page stating "Missing core name in path".

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're working with a multicore configuration, thus your admin page url is not just: `http://localhost:8080/solr/admin` but it has to contain the core name like this `http://localhost:8080/solr/${core}/admin`. Please replace `${core}` with your core name.

Otherwise you can go to the url `http://localhost:8080/solr` and you should see a list of the available cores, where you can click on a specific core and go directly to its admin page.

Comment: Any links on how I could configure solr/eclipse/tomcat on a single core configuration?

Comment: @Ramprakash Well, you should have a `solr.xml` file in your `$SOLR_HOME` containing the list of the cores you have like explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#Configuration).

Comment: Thanks @javanna. Actually I just had a typo in my solr.xml, hadn't closed my Context and that was the reason for the disaster. Identified it and now solr is up and running. Thanks again :)